# URL without www to www - using mod_rewrite and CodeIgniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm maintaining a website which was in most part developed by another developers team. I'm developing new functionalities, but sometimes I don't know how exactly some old code works. The website was developed using CodeIgniter and there is a simple .htaccess file containing a single rule. I'm not that good at PHP or mod_rewrite, so I need your help please.

In the .htaccess file there is these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I was searching Google about mod_rewrite and I suppose the code above checks if what is being requested is not a file or directory, and if not, it rewrites the URL inserting index.php?/ after the domain. So for example if I request http://www.example.net/teste it would be rewritten as http://www.example.net/index.php?/teste. am I right? I also suppose it was done to match the CodeIgniter's URL format that includes the index.php from the framework, right? But what I think is curious is that I'm not able to see the index.php?/ in the URL even after the RewriteRule terminate executing(but that's fine, it is exactly what I want).

My problem now is that I want to redirect all URL without www to a URL with www. So, I tried to insert these 2 lines in the final of the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

It works, but now I can see the index.php?/ part in URL. I don't want the index.php?/ part to be shown.

am I doing something wrong? Do you know a way to include the www in the URL without showing the index.php?/ part.

Thank you.

==================

UPDATE with answer:

Hey guys,

I modified my .htaccess to appear like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vesteer\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It worked. Everything's OK now.

Thank you for all replies.

Comment: An example the problem I'm facing. If I access:

"example.net/teste"

I'm being redirected to:

"www.example.net/index.php?/teste"

but what I want is to be redirected to:

"www.example.net/teste"

Comment: Hi anubhava, do you mean change the order of rules? I tried that and it did not work. The same problem.

Comment: When I alter the order, in Firefox the same problem and in Chrome the rewrite does not occur and the images don't appear anymore.

Comment: hey anubhava, I found a link that helped me to solve the problem. I could not let an answer as a post because I received this message: "We are no longer accepting answers from this account". But I left some comments in the page explaning how I did fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok find your solution, just update you .htaccess codes

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi Softbazz, thank you for your reply. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the RewriteCond you posted you are checking if the URL starts with www, and I want to rewrite URLs that don't starts with www. I want to rewrite non-www to www.

Comment: @Bruno: so you mean like some sub-domain link asif.softbazz.com to www.asif.softbazz.com

Comment: Softbazz, I needed to put www in domain, not sub-domain. example.net to become www.example.net. I can't post my answer as a post, because I receive this message: "We are no longer accepting answers from this account.". But I'll put my answer bellow as comments if anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Hey guys,

I found this link https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html and modified my .htaccess to appear like that:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
    
    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

It worked. Everything OK now.

Thank you for all replies.

Comment: Another observation, I needed to clear browser cache to see the rewrite occur after modifying the .htaccess.